# Hash xml parse to json shows does not have valid root

Tags: ruby-on-rails, xml, json

am converting xml file to json, it throws error

```
The document "some xml data" does not have a valid root.
```

am using json gem to conver, my code is

```
 require 'json'
 scheduledoc = "xmlfile"
 scheduleData = Hash.from_xml(scheduleDoc).to_json
 puts "schedule json #{scheduleData}
```

how to convert xml to json in rails.

Comment: Can you post the XML?

Answer (score 0):

Can we see the xml file?

First of all, make sure it begins with the right doctype.

example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

Then, try to wrap the entire document in a single tag

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root>
  <sometag></sometag>
  <sometag></sometag>

  <someothertag>
    <othercontent><othercontent>
    ...
  </someothertag>
</root>
```